# PostgreSQL trigger to avoid duplicate values in jsonb

Tags: postgresql, triggers, jsonb

I need to check if a value inside a jsonb is already present in a array. I'm trying to achieve this with a trigger but i'm new to this language and I don't know how to write the query.

```
    CREATE TABLE merchants (
      key uuid PRIMARY KEY,
      data jsonb NOT NULL
    )
```

Here is the trigger. I think the NEW.data.ids part is wrong.

```
CREATE FUNCTION validate_id_constraint() returns trigger as $$
    DECLARE merchants_count int;
  BEGIN
    merchants_count := (SELECT count(*) FROM merchants WHERE data->'ids' @> NEW.data.ids);
    IF (merchants_count != 0) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Duplicate id';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ language plpgsql;

  CREATE TRIGGER validate_id_constraint_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON merchants
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_id_constraint();
```

When i insert into the table i get this error message

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "data"
LINE 1: ...LECT count(*) FROM merchants WHERE data->'ids' @> NEW.data.i...
                                                            ^
```

I have done the query outside the trigger and it works fine

```
   SELECT count(*) FROM merchants WHERE data->'ids' @> '["11176", "11363"]'
```

Comment: Please show the structure of your JSON, particularly the `ids`.

Comment: It is just an array of strings
 {
    "ids": ["1", "2", "3"]
  }

Comment: And you only want to error out if the array is *contained* in an existing array, not if there are *overlaps*?

Comment: If they intersect. I guess the ?| is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you are using `.` instead of `->` to extract the `ids` array in the expression `NEW.data.ids`.

But your trigger won't work anyway because you are not trying to avoid containment, but overlaps in the arrays.

One way you could write the trigger function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_id_constraint() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   j jsonb;
BEGIN
   FOR j IN
      SELECT jsonb_array_elements(NEW.data->'ids')
   LOOP
      IF EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 FROM merchants WHERE j <@ (data->'ids'))
      THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'Duplicate IDs';
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;
```

You have to loop because there is no “overlaps” operator on `jsonb` arrays.

This is all slow and cumbersome because of your table design.

**Note 1:** You would be *much* better off if you only store data in `jsonb` that you do not need to manipulate in the database. In particular, you should store the `ids` array as field in the table. Then you can use the “overlaps” operator `&&` and speed that up with a `gin` index.

You would be even faster if you normalized the table structure and stored the individual array entries in a separate table, then a regular unique constraint would do.

**Note 2:** Any constraint enabled by a trigger suffers from a race condition: if two concurrent `INSERT`s conflict with each other, the trigger function will not see the values from the concurrent `INSERT` and you may end up with inconsistent data.